# Exception while run-app using activiti plugin

Tags: grails, activiti

I am using Grails 2.3, sts3.3, activiti5.12.1
and I followed steps from this link:https://code.google.com/p/grails-activiti-plugin/wiki/VacationRequestSampleApplication

Everything works fine until `grails run-app`, where I get the below exception:

```
| Loading Grails 2.3.0
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Running Grails application
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/HC_WFFA_WEB
Configuring Activiti Process Engine ...
... finished configuring Activiti Process Engine.
Configuring Activiti Process Engine with Spring Security ...
... finished configuring Activiti Process Engine with Spring Security.
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
Error initializing the application: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.services.ServiceBeanAliasPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ServiceBeanAliasPostProcessor.groovy:54)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:153)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:169)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your interest to the plugin. An user of the plugin found a workaround for this issue and it had been tracked at https://github.com/limcheekin/activiti/issues/18